# checkbox with scrollbar tkinter

Tags: python, parsing, tkinter

I'm parsing an hmmscan file with tkinter , im trying to print all domains using checkbutton so that the user can select them. the problem is the window is too small to handle the quantity of information.
can anyone help please?

````
  def hmmscan_parser(self):

        for qresult in SearchIO.parse(self.chemin, 'hmmscan3-domtab'):
            #print("%s %s" % (qresult.id))
            self.query_id = qresult.id  #sequence ID from fasta
            self.query_len = qresult.seq_len
            self.hits = qresult.hits
            self.num_hits = len(self.hits)
            if self.num_hits > 0:
                for i in range(0,self.num_hits):
                    #print(num_hits)
                    self.hit_evalue = self.hits[i].evalue #evalue
                    self.hmm_name = self.hits[i].accession
                    self.hmm_length = self.hits[i].seq_len

                check=Checkbutton(self.frame,text=self.query_id,variable=self.hit_evalue).pack(anchor=W , expand=YES) ```
````